# Zlib: Node.js can't extract compressed data from python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sqlite, zlib

I use python to compress string data and store the data in sqlite3. For my project I need also to use node.js to extract the data. The problem is, when i try to do that. I get a error from node.js:

{ Error: incorrect header check
    at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }

I tried to encode the string in Python with Base64 and utf8. Both doesn't make a difference.

In JavaScript i tried to skip some bits of the encode data, so that I may overcome the head check problem. That's also in vain.

Here is the compress code in python

```
import zlib, base64
import time
text = 'STACK OVERFLOW STACK OVERFLOW STACK OVERFLOW STACK OVERFLOW '
textToBytes = text.encode('utf-8')
code =  zlib.compress(textToBytes)

code = base64.b64encode(code)
print('code in base64:', code)

timestamp = time.time()
#Store in database
conn = sqlite3.connect('testsDummy.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp REAL, code TEXT)")
conn.commit()
c.execute("INSERT INTO  tests (code ,timestamp) VALUES (?,?)",(code ,timestamp))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Now this is code in node.js

```
function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
  var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = buffer[i];
  }
  return arrayBuffer;
}

app.get('/download/logfile/:timestamp', (req, res) => {
  var zlib = require('zlib');

  var db = new sqlite3.Database(path.join(__dirname, 'dependencies', 'testsDummy.db'));
  db.serialize(() => {
    db.all('SELECT code FROM tests WHERE timestamp=' + req.params.timestamp, (error, tests) => {
      db.close();

      if (tests[0].code== '' || tests[0].code== null) {
        res.send('No qdxm data collected.');
      }
      else {
        console.log(tests[0].code)
        var arrayBuffer = toArrayBuffer(Buffer.from(tests[0].code, 'base64'));
        zlib.gunzip(Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, 4), function (err, uncompressedMessage) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send();
          }
          else {
            res.json({ uncompressedMessage: uncompressedMessage.toString() })
            console.log(uncompressedMessage.toString())
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You write `BytesTotext` to the database, which is the decompressed data. You also have `timestamp, BytesTotext` reversed in your first insert (also, why are there two inserts?).

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry for the confusion. I tried to change some irrelvant inputs, so that people may better understand. But clearly I made some mistakes. Already correct the code above now. Thank you for pointing it out.@kichik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zlib.compress` in Python (without a `wbits` parameter) will generate the zlib format, whereas `zlib.gunzip` in Node.js is expecting the gzip format. Either use `zlib.compress` with `wbits` equal to 31 to get the gzip format, or use `zlib.inflate` in Node.js to decompress the zlib format.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I tried your methods. Well `zlib.compress` doesn't have an argument `wbits`. But `zlib.compressobj` has. So I tried somthing like: `zlib.compressobj(wbits = 31).compress()`. But unfortunately I got the same header check like before. So is the same with `zlib.inflate`.

Comment: It turns out, when I delect `code = base64.b64encode(code)`. Then `zlib.inflate` will do the job.  Thanks @Mark Adler