# Decode EU covid passport with nodejs

Tags: node.js, zlib, base45

I wanted to try to decode my EU covid passport, and found these [instructions for python](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-decode-your-own-eu-vaccination-green-pass-with-a-few-lines-of-python-9v2c37s1). I was trying to do it in nodejs which I am more familiar with

There is a 3 stage process

- decode Base 45
- decompress
- extract cose data

I have the code below, but the cose.encrypt.read is hitting the catch method with an error `Unknown tag, 18`

Any ideas?

```
const base45 = require("base45");
const zlib = require("zlib");
const cose = require("cose-js");

passport =
    "HC1:NCFO...";

// removes HC1:
payload = passport.slice(4);

// returns buffer
const decoded = base45.decode(payload);

// Use inflate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652769/zlib-node-js-cant-extract-compressed-data-from-python
const decompressed = zlib.inflateSync(decoded);
console.log(decompressed);

cose.encrypt
    .read(decompressed)
    .then((buf) => {
        console.log("Protected message: " + buf.toString("utf8"));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("!!", error);
    });
```

Comment: I am stuck at last step too, but I don't know anything anout node.js, I only know browser javascript; I succesfully decoded the BASE45 string and the zlib string, but the decoding of the resulting string using CBOR.js library fails, any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with more details of the error you experience. I may be able to answer now that I've made more progress in understanding things, and I am doing it in the browser too

Comment: Currently I am not authorized to post any more question.

Answer (score 0):

I subsequently found https://dev.to/lmillucci/javascript-how-to-decode-the-greenpass-qr-code-3dh0 which had a working nodejs solution in it :-)